# Is there a python cryptographic libraries like the MIRACL library?

Tags: library, python, encryption

MIRACL (Multiprecision Integer and Rational Arithmetic C/C++ Library) is a famous library used most of the time for implementing number-theoretic based methods of cryptography. I don't know how to code in C and C++ so I was wondering are there other libraries like MIRACL but for python?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MIRACL and I don't know what features you're looking for, anyway, but Python has arbitrary-sized integers (`int`) and rational numbers (`fractions.Fraction`) built in.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, you can use Charm: https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/install_source.html

In Charm, you will find a wide range of implemented schemes that can be easily used, please see this example for the RSA public key encryption https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/charm/schemes/pkenc/pkenc_rsa.html

This is a list of all the implemented cryptographic protocols: https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/schemes.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not familiar with MIRACL but one very good Python Cryptographic library would be [PyCryptoDome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/). You can find it's documentation [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How do we know it supports multiprecision?

Answer (score 0):

### **MIRACL is a core cryptographic library implemented in python as follows.**

1. Paper “MIRACL Cryptographic SDK: Multiprecision Integer and Rational
   Arithmetic Cryptographic Library.” [Online]. Available:
   https://github. com/miracl/MIRACL (Accessed: Dec. 2021).
2. GitHub Codes------>https://github.com/miracl/core/tree/master/python